# How to shut down `ssh2` sftp server programatically

Tags: node.js, sftp, ssh2-sftp

I am using the [`ssh2` library](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) to create a sftp server for testing during my testing suite. The server starts successfully and tests run as expected - all is great.

However, after all of the tests have been conducted the testing script does not exit as the sftp server process is still listening/executing.

How can I programatically shut down the sftp server?

Comment: Can you include the code how you start the server so we can try reproduce it?

Comment: Maybe these methods help:  https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback /
    https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_server_unref  - docs of the lib state "Server instances also have the same methods/properties/events as net.Server."

Comment: @TobiasK I replicated this script to start the server: https://github.com/validityhq/node-sftp-server/blob/master/server_example.js

Comment: @TobiasK you are the best! Your proposal worked. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Server instances also have the same methods/properties/events as [`net.Server`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_class_net_server).

These look promising:

- [`server.close()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback)
- [`server.unref()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_server_unref)